# I cannot connect to mobile broadband network

Tags: networking, internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I'm using Ubuntu gnome 14.04.3. Today all of a sudden I cannot connect to my MTS Broadband network. it is displayed in the nm applet but when I click on it says connecting and the it says 'off'. I tried several times. I unplugged and then again plugged the modem in my computer but with no result. I restated my computer several times. no result. I even deleted the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection`.

Then again created new connection but no result. I only remember adding these lines:

```
IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

After watching this video

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqBjkSqSmBo`
```

(the first line I actually typed '#' without the coutes. I cannot write it w/o the quotes here)

How can I connect to the network using GUI?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the three lines again?

Comment: I've written it as an answer, if you accept that, people that find your question in the future can see it was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines you added.

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then remove the following lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```